# Format date in Meteor Handlebars bracers {{ timestamp }}

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, meteor, handlebars.js

When using Meteor's Handlebar bracers, how do you convert the output of `{{ timestamp }}` from  `Thu Jul 25 2013 19:33:19 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` to `Jul 25`?

Tried `{{ timestamp.toString('yyyy-MM-dd') }}` but it gave an error

Comment: Note: The standard [`toString()` for `Date`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) ignores any arguments passed to it and ECMAScript doesn't define any other methods that can format a `Date` based on a `String` like `'yyyy-MM-dd'`. If you're not already including a library which modifies `toString()`, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1056728 for suggestions.

Comment: here's a better description how to do this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580495/format-a-date-from-inside-a-handlebars-template-in-meteor

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use a handlebars helper:

```
Template.registerHelper("prettifyDate", function(timestamp) {
    return new Date(timestamp).toString('yyyy-MM-dd')
});
```

Then in your html:

```
{{prettifyDate timestamp}}
```

If you use moment:

```
Template.registerHelper("prettifyDate", function(timestamp) {
    return moment(new Date(timestamp)).fromNow();
});
```

Comment: As @JonathanLonowski noted above, it's worth noting that `timestamp.toString()` will ignore any arguments passed to it.
I find that using MomentJS makes all of this incredibly simple.

Comment: @Akshat, note that after some flip flopping, the syntax is now [`Template.registerHelper`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me.

toString("yyyy-MM-dd") - doesn't convert it.

```
Template.registerHelper("prettifyDate", function(timestamp) {
    var curr_date = timestamp.getDate();
    var curr_month = timestamp.getMonth();
    curr_month++;
    var curr_year = timestamp.getFullYear();
    result = curr_date + ". " + curr_month + ". " + curr_year;
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("prettifyDate", function(timestamp) {
     return (new Date(timestamp)).format("yyyy-MM-dd");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use a handlebars helper:**

```
const exphbsConfig = exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    helpers:{

        prettifyDate:  function(timestamp) {
            function addZero(i) {
                if (i < 10) {
                  i = "0" + i;
                }
                return i;
            }

            var curr_date = timestamp.getDate();
            var curr_month = timestamp.getMonth();
            curr_month++;
            var curr_year = timestamp.getFullYear();

            var curr_hour = timestamp.getHours();
            var curr_minutes = timestamp.getMinutes();
            var curr_seconds = timestamp.getSeconds();

            result = addZero(curr_date)+ "/" + addZero(curr_month) + "/" + addZero(curr_year)+ '   ' +addZero(curr_hour)+':'+addZero(curr_minutes)+':'+addZero(curr_seconds);
            return result;
        }

    }    

});

app.engine('hbs', exphbsConfig.engine);
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

**Then in your html:**

```
  <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Atualizada em: {{prettifyDate updatedAt}}    </small>
    </div>
```