# Format a date from inside a Handlebars Template in Meteor

Tags: javascript, datetime, meteor, handlebars.js, date-format

I got a ISO formatted Date from my Data and what I actually want to do, is to modify my date format directly from my Templates.

like this:

```
{{format my.context.date "myFormat"}}
```

I'm using the moment library, so I could write something like this:

```
{{formatDate my.context.date "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"}} // 03.09.2013 18:12
```

It would be nice, because I think it's the place where I should be able to do this. In my template.

Comment: Any chance you could follow the Q&A formatting that StackOverflow uses? i.e. post the question with your solution. Otherwise someone my mistake this for an advert and kill it. Also don't forget to accept your answer!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, and maybe someone will find it useful.
In most projects you have a couple of date formats you want to use.
So it's a good approach to define your formats with readable names.

For this example I took just 'short' and 'long', but you will see, it's very easy to extend.

So I created an Object in my Client Script:

```
var DateFormats = {
       short: "DD MMMM - YYYY",
       long: "dddd DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm"
};
```

Also, I created a Handlebars Helper "formatDate".

Edited: Now you should use UI instead of Handlebars

```
// Deprecated since version 0.8.0 
Handlebars.registerHelper("formatDate", function(datetime, format) {

// Use UI.registerHelper..
UI.registerHelper("formatDate", function(datetime, format) {
  if (moment) {
    // can use other formats like 'lll' too
    format = DateFormats[format] || format;
    return moment(datetime).format(format);
  }
  else {
    return datetime;
  }
});
```

As you can see, I use the moment.js lib in my Helper. To install it, just type `meteor add momentjs:moment` from your command line.

And now, everywhere in my Templates I can use it with the two params, like this:

```
{{formatDate MyISOString "short"}} // 02 September - 2013
{{formatDate MyISOString "long"}} //  Monday 02.09.2013 18:00
```

If you want to create your own formats, take a look at the momentjs docs http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: last nag, please accept your answer it helps search results ;)

Comment: This is failing for me at the if(moment) test (Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: undefined is not a function) which sort of makes sense.  I tried (datetime instanceof moment) but that returns false... what should this be?

Comment: Sorry, is failing for a different reason.  I'm inputting a moment into datetime, with return moment(datetime) I get a string back with a full timezoned value. If I add .format("Anything at all") I get, Exception from Deps recompute function: TypeError: undefined is not a function. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for the late answer. Maybe, there is an issue with the loading order of your libraries. Have you installed moment with mrt?

Comment: You should use `var f = DateFormats[format]`, otherwise you are leaking a global `f` variable

Comment: you can now install the package directly without meteorite: `meteor add momentjs:moment`

Comment: How can I register helper function in nestjs built on on typescript

Comment: At the time of writing, moment.js is currently considered legacy software, is no longer adding new features, and its maintainers generally recommend replacing it. See [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).