# How to localize (i18n) moment.js within meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, meteor, momentjs

How can moment.js used within a meteor.js app be told to use another language than English? moment.js (installed as an mrt package) works fine with the default English language.

Using the demo calls from the moment.js docs at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-language/ always produces 'en'. I noticed there is a German language file for moment in meteor_project/packages/moment/lib/moment/lang/de.js that doesn't seem to be used though?

To specify: within a template helper I tried: 
moment.lang('de');
return moment.lang() //will result to 'en'

and the other options mentioned here: [Format a date from inside a Handlebars Template in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580495/format-a-date-from-inside-a-handlebars-template-in-meteorbe)

Comment: Did you include `moment-with-langs.js`? I have no idea about mrt package...

Comment: No I only included meteor with mrt add meteor. phoenix added the missing information in his anwser, now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed `moment` as

`mrt add moment`

Then you already got the languages, but you have to include them manually. Find them at `packages\moment\lib\lang`. To include them, go to the `package.js` file and add the language of your choice after all the other files.

`api.add_files('lib/moment/lang/de.js', 'client')`

[image: modify package.js]

And there you go!

[image: proof]

Comment: Excellent! I wonder why this information is not included at https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment or maybe I missed it?

Comment: This doesn't work in Meteor 1.0.3.2. The structure is not the same. I'm looking around on how to fix it. Maybe you know?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [rzymek](https://github.com/rzymek/meteor-moment/)'s packages.

> These packages use the offical momentjs:moment Meteor package.
>
> **Locales:**
>
> To add a specific locale user
>
> `meteor add rzymek:moment-locale-pl`
>
> The complete list of locales can be obtained by
>
> `meteor search rzymek:moment-locale-.*`
>
> To add all locales use:
>
> `meteor add rzymek:moment-locales`

Answer (score 5):

As for today (July 2015) I've done this:

Download [locales.min.js](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/min/locales.min.js) from Moment.js github repository and put it somewhere inside client folder of your app.

I've choose `client/lib/moment/locales.min.js`
Then you can set any locale you like (that moment js have) and change it according to user account settings.

```
moment.locale('en')
// or
moment.locale('ru')
```

What I don't like is that all languages are combined in one file. Even though it's not too large there are still some work to do (ajax calls or something like that to grab only locale file you need)

---

By the way. If you don't need all supported languages you can grab  [locale files](https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/locale).
I believe meteor.js will automatically minify this files when you go to production

Comment: FYI, you should put library files like this inside `client/compatibility` to ensure proper load order and to speed up Meteor build times (since it won’t try to evaluate the files in that special folder).

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the Meteorite package. Include Moment.js client-side along with whatever language files you need.

1. `mrt remove moment`
2. Create a folder `client/compatibility/moment` in your project.
3. Save http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js into `client/compatibility/moment`.

That's it. You don't need to add any `<script>` tags, nothing. Because Moment.js is in the `client/compatibility` subfolder, any client-side code that's loaded from `client` or any other subfolder of `client` will run *after* Moment.js has been loaded.

Comment: That link is broken and I can't seem to find the file that it is referencing via Google.

Comment: I think the current equivalent is http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not get that working initially since I accidentally included moment.js in my project twice, but now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that their is still just the momentum.js installed without translations if you do the official "meteor add  momentjs:moment" until today.
My workaround: Just open [moment-with-locales.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js) and Str-F your desired language (in my case german) and copy and past the:

```
// moment.js locale configuration
// locale : german (de)
// author : lluchs : 
// author: Menelion Elensúle: 

(function (factory) {
    ...
}`
```

in a momentum.js file in e.g. client/lib folder. Reload and their you go with  moment.locale('de') ... since moment.lang('de') is deprecated .

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for having translation.

You have to install "momentjs:moment".

After that you have to use the following lines for each language you want to add. I put it on my main.js file.

```html
// French translation for moment JS
moment.locale('fr', {
    months : "janvier_février_mars_avril_mai_juin_juillet_août_septembre_octobre_novembre_décembre".split("_"),
    monthsShort : "janv._févr._mars_avr._mai_juin_juil._août_sept._oct._nov._déc.".split("_"),
    weekdays : "dimanche_lundi_mardi_mercredi_jeudi_vendredi_samedi".split("_"),
    weekdaysShort : "dim._lun._mar._mer._jeu._ven._sam.".split("_"),
    weekdaysMin : "Di_Lu_Ma_Me_Je_Ve_Sa".split("_"),
    longDateFormat : {
        LT : "HH:mm",
        LTS : "HH:mm:ss",
        L : "DD/MM/YYYY",
        LL : "D MMMM YYYY",
        LLL : "D MMMM YYYY LT",
        LLLL : "dddd D MMMM YYYY LT"
    },
    calendar : {
        sameDay: "[Aujourd'hui à] LT",
        nextDay: '[Demain à] LT',
        nextWeek: 'dddd [à] LT',
        lastDay: '[Hier à] LT',
        lastWeek: 'dddd [dernier à] LT',
        sameElse: 'L'
    },
    relativeTime : {
        future : "dans %s",
        past : "il y a %s",
        s : "quelques secondes",
        m : "une minute",
        mm : "%d minutes",
        h : "une heure",
        hh : "%d heures",
        d : "un jour",
        dd : "%d jours",
        M : "un mois",
        MM : "%d mois",
        y : "une année",
        yy : "%d années"
    },
    ordinalParse : /\d{1,2}(er|ème)/,
    ordinal : function (number) {
        return number + (number === 1 ? 'er' : 'ème');
    },
    meridiemParse: /PD|MD/,
    isPM: function (input) {
        return input.charAt(0) === 'M';
    },
    // in case the meridiem units are not separated around 12, then implement
    // this function (look at locale/id.js for an example)
    // meridiemHour : function (hour, meridiem) {
    //     return /* 0-23 hour, given meridiem token and hour 1-12 */
    // },
    meridiem : function (hours, minutes, isLower) {
        return hours < 12 ? 'PD' : 'MD';
    },
    week : {
        dow : 1, // Monday is the first day of the week.
        doy : 4  // The week that contains Jan 4th is the first week of the year.
    }
});
```

And then no more `"ReferenceError: module is not defined"`. For info I use `momentjs:moment@2.11.0`.